# How to display top 10 feature importance for random forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was wondering if it's possible to only display the top 10 feature_importance for random forest.

Here's my code:

```
model1 = RandomForestClassifier()
model1.fit(X_train, y_train)
pd.Series(model1.feature_importances_, index=X_train.columns)
```

I tried the above and the result I get is the full list of all 70+ features, and not in any order.

```
MonthlyMinutes               0.048203
TotalRecurringCharge         0.028393
MonthlyRevenue               0.041576
DirectorAssistedCalls        0.019973
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Pandas documentation, e.g. Series at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

and try:

```
model1 = RandomForestClassifier() model1.fit(X_train, y_train) 
myClassifiers = pd.Series(model1.feature_importances_, index=X_train.columns)
myClassifiers.sort_values(ascending=False)`
print (myClasifiers.head(10))
```

Comment: thank you so much. appreciate your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have it figured out at this point, but for future searchers, here is code that will work better:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
features = pd.Series(clf.feature_importances_, index=all_x_vars)
features.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
print(features.head(10))
```

The `inplace=True` is an important addition